# Infinite Limit Approaches

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I was doing my book-work when I encountered a problem that I did not know how to approach or solve. The problem is as follows. $$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{x-\sqrt{x^2+5}}$$
I did not know which method to use to solve it, and apparently, the answer is $0.5$.

At this point, I have not learned the lhopital rule and I am not supposed to solve it graphically.

Comment: Did you try multiplying by $1$? Multiply top and bottom by $x + \sqrt{x^2+5}$ and see if that does it.

Comment: @AlfredYerger that wouldn't work. (the denominator is actually going to negative infinity)

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{x-\sqrt{x^2+5}}
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{-u}{-u-\sqrt{(-u)^2+5}} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{u}{u+\sqrt{u^2+5}} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1+5u^{-2}}} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1+5\cdot0}} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}$$

[Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/c2cjcc1nj7):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{x}{x-\sqrt{x^2+5}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x^2}}}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

About $\infty$, $x^2+k\sim x^2$ so
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{x-\sqrt{x^2+5}}=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{x-\sqrt{x^2}}=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{x-|x|}=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{x+x}=\dfrac12$$